# Badly formatted emails when forwarding

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, webclient

Has anyone else seen this problem?
I read my email in a browser (same problem with IE11, FireFox, Chrome, Edge).
We get our email from our on-site MS Exchange Server.

When I use the "forward" button to forward an inbound email to another user,
it sometimes displays the original email quotes with odd/broken formatting.

The text will look like it's shifted to the far left margin, in a thin column
only 200-300 pixels wide.  Or sometimes in a column far wider than my entire screen.

We notice that problem more often with email that has been forwarded through
multiple users on small iPhone devices, Android phones, etc

Has anyone else experienced that problem, or have a solution or workaround?

See attached image. [Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtHIo.png)

Comment: Have you got your issue fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, seems I have not met similar issues yet. Can this issue be a little better if you clear the browser cache and re-open the web mail? Also, please check if you have any antivirus software which might influence this issue.